# Radio buttons not working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, radio-button

I've done a lot of research on this, but still have not been able to determine why my buttons  are not working. They work if you double click them, but not single click. The inputs are not wrapped in label tags.

```
<div id="map-overlay">
<div id="filters" class="menu-ui">
    <form>

        <label for="Perm. < 5 years" class="radio-label"></label>
        <input id="Perm. < 5 years" name="checkbox" type="radio">


        <label for="Temp. < 5 years" class="radio-label"></label>
        <input id="Temp. < 5 years" name="checkbox" type="radio">


        <label for="Temp. > 5 years" class="radio-label"></label>
        <input id="Temp. > 5 years" name="checkbox" type="radio">


        <label for="Perm. > 5 years" class="radio-label"></label>
        <input id="Perm. > 5 years" name="checkbox" type="radio">

    </form>
</div>
```

These work fine in Chrome, Safari, etc.

Comment: They seem to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/cyd0jdah/ - are you sure it's not some other part of your code that's causing the problem? Also your IDs are crazy.

Comment: I'm not sure if its another part of my code, like that the buttons are in an overlay on top of another element? But they work in everybrowser but FF, where you have to double click.

Comment: Unless you post more code or preferably a link to a demonstration it's hard to say anything more. The part you posted works fine.

Comment: The inputs are being generated by data files that I'm loading here. I think that may have something to do with it, since like you said everything else works http://jsfiddle.net/mtown/urtx23c0/

Comment: Again, those radio buttons work fine, but why are you setting an event handler *inside* an event handler in your JS code?

Answer (score 0):

First I think you should re think your Ids since they look malformed and would not be very useful for targeting via css.

Second I think your HTML should look more like this

```
    <label for="Permlt5Years" class="radio-label">
         Perm. < 5 years
         <input id="Permlt5Years" name="checkbox" type="radio">
    </label>
```

Clicking on a label should select a radio button for you. When validating via direct input here https://validator.w3.org/check against html5 doctype it had 11 errors.

Comment: Even with rethinking my IDs, I'm still getting the same result. Also, I've read wrapping the input in a label tag works in all browsers but Firefox.

Comment: @mtown: Wrapping an input in a label works perfectly fine in Firefox.